# Find the corresponding value in another column of the same row for a value that you have named

Tags: r

Within the data.frame I've named "peak" I have two columns, Time and VLICG. To give some context, VLICG is a sigmoidal curve. I have successfully located the start of the curve and needed to find a value of VLICG that is 10% above the start of the rise in the curve. This value is not exactly within the data frame so I ran the code:

```
temp<-peak[!peak==run.vlICG]

closest.value<-temp[which.min(abs(temp-run.vlICG))]
```

To find the value closest to the value that is 10% above the start of the curve. This worked fine. However, now the issue I face is that I want the corresponding value in the "Time" column for this value that I have named "closest.value". This seems like an easy question but I cannot figure it out. Maybe it can't be done in this way since the named value ("closest.value") cannot be identified in this way in the data.frame "peak"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time please give some reproducible data, but if I understand correctly what you mean, I think you simply need this:

```
peak$Time[peak$VlICG==closest.value]
```

Comment: Thanks@user3640617. That works perfectly. Yes next time I will give some data.